# Fastest way to remove `..` and related folder from path?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

### The question

Given a path like thus:

```
G:\path\foo\..\bar\baz.txt
```

Which we can immediately parse in our minds, and as the OS will parse as:

```
G:\path\bar\baz.txt
```

What's the fastest way to do that programmatically? **In other words, does a library function already exist that will do this for me cleanly so that I don't botch it myself.**

### My first shot at an answer

```
// in pseudocode
string[] s = input.split('\')
string output
for ( int i = s.length ; i > 0 ; i-- ) {
  if ( s[i] == ".." ) i--;
  else output = s[i] + "\" + output
}
return output
```

But notice that this answer doesn't cover the case (unexpected, but potential) for

```
G:\path\foo\..\..\bar\baz.txt
```

which would of course be

```
G:\bar\baz.txt
```

TSQL functions will work as well!!!!!

---

#### Not important to the question but I felt like sharing ;)

I'm passing it from a returned value (off a webservice call) into a sproc (for XML shredding) and want to eliminate the `foo\..\` as the value I pass in is used as the key for preventing duplicate processing later. If I insert `G:\path\foo\..\bar\baz.txt` and another script inserts `G:\path\bar\baz.txt` the file will be processed twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static string System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(string path)
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"G:\path\foo\..\..\bar\baz.txt");
```

Comment: ~ Thanks for the faster response, hope you don't mind my awarding to Alan to help push him up?